# How to handle refresh and auth tokens at client side? (where to store)

Tags: security, authentication, vue.js, jwt, single-page-application

I am using laravel for back-end, and vue for front-end.

When user wants to authenticate he makes call to my laravel api and gets Auth token and refresh token. Auth token is valid only 2 min, but refresh token is long lived. So if I save refresh token somewhere in user side, he can stay logged in for a long time, but I am worried about safety, if I save refresh token in a local storage, it's vulnerable. I can save auth token in local storage becouse it's short lived and even if it gets stolen I don't care, but I don't know how to handle refresh token.

The hard part is I don't want to make user enter his/her credentials every time he opens the application.

So the question is, where can I save refresh token? and where auth token?

Answer (score 2):

It only makes sense to use a refresh token if you store it different from the access token. If it's stored the same, it only increases complexity but both will be compromised the same way.

You could store the refresh token in a httponly cookie though, even better if the cookie is for a different domain (the idp), but it makes sense on the same domain too. The idea is that even if the access token is compromised in an attack like xss, the refresh token is still inaccessible.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, especially the first sentence. I was struggling to find a reason to use refresh tokens and was thinking I'm missing something here.